# how to install custom font in azure app service

Tags: asp.net, azure, pdf, ms-word

We are using asp.net web api for converting MS word to pdf which are using custom fonts

and these asp.net web api had to be deployed in azure app service.

How this can be feasible?

Comment: Include it in your app files?

Answer (score 0):

Apps deployed in App Service run in a sandbox with limited access to the OS so it's not possible to install fonts as you would do on your desktop.  Also, keep in mind that many PDF libraries don't work because they rely on GDI functions that are not available in the sandbox.  The solution is to use a VM.